# Not Between with linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

This is my query :

```
var model = (from p in entity.vehicule
             join y in entity.indisponible on p.Matv equals y.idv
             where p.agence.idgov == idv && (!(dd1 >= y.Dd && dd1 <= y.Df) || !(df1 >= y.Dd && df1 <= y.Df))
             select p).ToList();
```

I have tried with many ways to write this part :

```
(!(dd1 >= y.Dd && dd1 <= y.Df) || !(df1 >= y.Dd && df1 <= y.Df))
```

In this way(this is how it has to be look in sql):

```
(dd1 Not Between Date(y.dd) And Date(y.dF)) OR (df1 Not Between Date(y.dd) And Date(y.df))
```

> dd1 is date (From), Df1 is date (to).

I think I'm missing something here :(

Comment: I'm not getting error but it show me error record records that's have not to be shown. post update it please check it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit 2: *After many comments, hopefully this is the result you're after***

```
public IList<Car> GetCarsAvailable(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    var result = from c in dataContext.Cars
                 where !c.Bookings.Any(b => (fromDate >= b.From && fromDate <= b.To) || (toDate >= b.From && toDate <= b.To))
                 select c;

    return result.ToList();
}
```

**Edit 1**

If we alter it slightly so instead of checking against a birthday, we'll check against `favourite days`. Not let us assume that a person can have multiple favourite days, and that we want to select everyone that doesn't have a favourite day, that is within 2 days. Let's write out our assumptions further:

- `Richard`'s favourite days are, `5 May 2012` and `10 September 2012`
- `Amy`'s favourite days are, `8 August 2012` and `12 December 2012`
- `Matthews`' favourite days is, `30 October 2012`

And let us say we want to find everyone who doesn't have a favourite day between `1 May 2012` and `1 September 2012`; our result output should only be `Matthew`, we could write:

```
public IList<Person> GetPeopleWhoDontHaveAnyFavouriteDate(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    var result = from p in dataContext.People
                 where !p.FavouriteDates.Any(f => f.Date >= fromDate && f.Date <= toDate)
                 select p;

    return result.ToList();
}
```

What the above statement is saying, is we want to select all people, but only if `none` of their favourite dates are between two dates.

Alternatively we could say, lets select a person, if they do have a date outside of a range. So assuming we wanted to check from `1 May 2012` to `1 November 2012`, so our result set was now `Richard` and `Amy`, this could be achieved like so:

```
public IList<Person> GetPeopleWhoDontHaveFavouriteDate(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    var result = from p in dataContext.People
                 where p.FavouriteDates.Any(f => f.Date < fromDate || f.Date > toDate)
                 select p;

    return result.ToList();
}
```

**Original**

*I found it tricky to read your abbreviated variables, so I hope you don't mind but I thought I'd write a quick demo how to do a "not between" two dates*.

I think you're on the right lines with things. Here are a couple of ways you could approach it. The following methods do the same thing, but one checks the inverse.

```
public IList<Person> GetPeopleNotBornFromTo(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    var result = from p in dataContext.People
                 where p.DateOfBirth < fromDate || p.DateOfBirth > toDate
                 select p;

    return result.ToList();
}

public IList<Person> GetPeopleNotBornFromTo2(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    var result = from p in dataContext.People
                 where !(p.DateOfBirth >= fromDate && p.DateOfBirth <= toDate)
                 select p;

    return result.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more because i'm using join so i dont know how to include this in my code??

Comment: I've updated the post to better reflect how you might check on child entities.

Comment: thanks, but the problem that i got not unvailable date(From-to) and i have to check if my day is in this unvailable date, The opossite what u have writed. can u check up my post i have update it

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question; let's try to clarify. Are you trying to determine if a date range, is not within another date range?

Comment: i want to find all avaible cars in a city between two dates `from and to`. So to do this i have to check that the date chosen by the user is not in the unavailable table. 
For example this car is unvailable(in the unvailbale table i got)

`From 01/04/201 to 26/04/2012 and From 01/05/2012 to 09/05/2012.`

So if user make search From 28/04/2012 to 30/04/2012 this car has to be shown 
Else if he make search From 28/04/2012 to 03/05/2012 this car will not be showed in search result.
I hope u get the point.